# Integration error numerical method

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, rounding-error

Is there someone who can help me with this?

[image]

I have found that the error is given by

$$
f(t) - p_n(t) = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} f^{(n+1)}(\xi_t) \prod_{k=0}^n \left(t - t_k \right)
$$
where the derivative is defined by

[image]

Can someone help me with some advice?

What integral did I actually have to solve?

I can't see what will happen with $ξ_t?$

Comment: You are not expected to compute the exact expression, determine its roots and compute the integrals on the segments between them. What is expected is that you sample the difference with for instance $10n+1$ samples or more and apply a numerical quadrature rule, using the half-density quadrature to estimate the error.

Comment: This question continues https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3412386/115115, see the image there on how large the value of the error can become.

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Lutz Lehmann. I don't think I really understand it. But I have found a formula in my notes that says:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/catz5.png) .
So if we take n=10 as example and look on the graph in math.stackexchange.com/a/3412386/115115 .
Then we can write the integral as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiBMt.png) 
If I try to solve this in Maple I get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sldVe.png).
Is that correct? Then I just have to solve the integral with a numerical method in stead of with Maple?

Comment: Please use comments to continue the comment discussion or extend your question (and perhaps use a comment to notify the changes.) Use an answer only for answering. // Apart from that, the integral over an absolute value can never give a negative result. Using the mean value theorem will give you a bound, but never the accuracy on the actual number that is required in the task.

Comment: Hi again. I don't really think I understand the problem. I have to use one numerical method to find the integral of f with a=0 and b=3? Then I now have solved it with the "trapez method" for n=10, n=50 and n=100. Furthermore I have found the "exact" value for the integral with Maple. Then the difference between the exact integral-value found with Maple and the intagral-value found with the "Trapez Method" is then the error?

Comment: It would help if you could enhance the question text by what you actually did and what results you got. From the present information you only get a "maybe".

Answer (score 0):

What was required of you was something like the following, possibly with hand-made implementations of the interpolation and quadrature functions.

````
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import exp, sin, cos, pi, linspace, polyval

f=lambda x: exp(-x)*cos(4*pi*x)
for n in [10,50,100]:
    x = linspace(0,3,n+1);
    y = f(x)
    pn = lagrange(x,y)
    s = [ quad(lambda t: abs(f(t)-pn(t)), x[k],x[k+1], epsabs=10**((n/10)**2-6), epsrel=5e-6, limit=200) for k in range(n) ]
    print n, sum(ss[0] for ss in s), sum(ss[1] for ss in s)```
````

which returns the list of error integrals and estimated error of that value

```
 10  1.92296458696      6.07592167557e-06
 50  8.31497502325e+24  1.11595406939e+15
100  1.90234868668e+68  2.11203131282e+54
```

This demonstrates the rapid growth of the error with rising degree.

If you use alternatively the Chebyshev points, you get the error integrals

````
for n in [10,50,100]:
    x = 3*cos(linspace(-pi,0,n+1));
    y = f(x)
    pn = lagrange(x,y)
    s = [ quad(lambda t: abs(f(t)-pn(t)), x[k],x[k+1], epsabs=10**((n/10)**2-6), epsrel=5e-6, limit=200) for k in range(n) ]
    print n, sum(ss[0] for ss in s), sum(ss[1] for ss in s)```
````

which returns the list of error integrals and estimated error of that value

```
 10  19.3439343927      1.06752067248e-06
 50  40449529.2343      0.0839580123975
100  3.26753638128e+32  3.64906319354e+18
```

This is slightly better than the equidistant result in the larger degrees.